# What is iMacros OR equivalent?

Tags: imacros

What is the equivalent of an OR operator in iMacros? I wanted to do something like this:

`(TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:u_0_10) || (TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:u_0_z)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think iMacros has operator or conditionals in the basic non scripting mode.

> We did not add such statements as we do not think that our customers should have to attend week-long seminars just to learn yet another proprietary scripting or programming language. In other words, iMacros commands refer to web page elements, so any programming logic must be put into a script that then uses iMacros to automate the website.
>   [-iMacros FAQ](http://wiki.imacros.net/FAQ#Q:_Are_there_conditional_statements_like_if..._then...else_in_the_iMacros_macro_language.3F)

To use conditionals or operators you should use iMacros scripting feature on Windows. (If you want to use Linux I would recommend looking into [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) as the scripting feature for iMacros for Linux is [no longer supported since 2012](http://wiki.imacros.net/Linux#iMacros_Scripting_Interface_for_Linux))

iMacros returns error codes to see if the command was completed successfully, in your case you can run the command "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:u_0_10" and if it returns 1 (1 means if was successful) continue else if it returns any number other than 1 run the command "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:u_0_z0".